# What is the correct type and size for a boot partition for BIOS?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, bios, boot-partition

About `Ubuntu` installation:

- it for either `Desktop` or `Server` environments
- for a hard disk based on either `HDD` or `SSD`

For a *latest* PC or laptop based with `UEFI` for boot purposes is recommended define `/boot/efi` with 1GB of space.

For an *old* PC or laptop where uses `BIOS` - therefore does **not** exist `UEFI` - for boot purposes, what should be the partition type and space recommended?

Comment: "what should be the partition type and space recommended?" ⇢ let the installer decide that. There's no need for anyone to manually define partitions anymore unless you really, *really* want to ...

Comment: If I want create in HD the `/` and `/home` partitions, therefore I must create the "boot" partition, right? - or If GParted is involved?

Comment: A /boot partition (not to be confused with a UEFI partition mounted at /boot/efi) is typically not needed these days, the /boot directory in root is used.  Really old PCs may need the kernel which is being booted near the beginning of the disk, hence the need for a /boot partition near the beginning. Logical Volume encryption may be another reason for a /boot partition (so the unencrypted kernel may boot).

Comment: @ubfan1 can you post your comment how an answer with some expansion/details for the audience? thank you. It to understand the difference for the old and new hardware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested, some background/expanded comment:

Bootloaders exist to run a kernel, wherever it is on the disk.

The term "boot partition" is a bit ambiguous, sometimes it may be used to refer to the partition with the "boot" flag, or to a partition holding the Linux kernels (/boot).

The two major partitioning types of PC disks, GPT and MSDOS  may each be used in either of two modes, UEFI or BIOS/legacy. Ubuntu may be installed on either partitioning type in either mode, but Windows 8/10 in UEFI mode requires GPT partitioning, and in legacy mode MSDOS partitioning. GPT/UEFI has been the standard on PCs for the last 10 years, so that is the preferred setup.  Sometimes a Windows update from Windows 7 in legacy mode may result in a Windows 10 installed on an MSDOS disk in legacy mode.

To boot in UEFI mode (assuming that capability in the hardware exists), either partition type needs an EFI partition with
1)a FAT filesystem,
2)the boot flag and
3)the ESP (EFI System Partition) flag.

The actual bootloaders (grubx64.efi, and shimx64.efi) are just files on this filesystem. Other bootloaders, e.g. bootmgfw.efi for Windows may exist on this filesystem. UEFI hardware can keep multiple bootloader locations in memory to allow you to select one, and additionally there is a default location and bootloader, /EFI/Boot/bootx64,efi, associated with the disk, and that does not need to in UEFI memory.

If the root filesystem is readable at this point (i.e. not encrypted, or on some filesystem unknown to grub, the kernel may be found and booted -- no other partitions needed.  If that's not the case, an unencrypted/known filesystem partition may be needed -- this is the (typically ext4 filesystem)
/boot partition.  See the below MSDOS section for /boot size recommendations.
Typically, this EFI partition gets mounted at /boot/efi, but that's just in case of updates for grub or shim -- that mount is not necessary for either booting or running.

Less than 50MB is used for my default, ubuntu, and Microsoft bootloaders, so a 200MB EFI partition seems sufficient.

BIOS mode is older, and more primitive.  It's bootloader is hardwired into sector zero of the disk (512 byte sectors).  One sector is too small for booting, so the bootloader then jumps to some location with the rest of its code.  On an MSDOS  partitioned disk, this location is typically stuck between partitions, not even in a filesystem.  On a GPT partitioned disk, there is no room to shoehorn in the rest of the bootloader between partitions, so an explicit place needs to be made for the code -- an unformatted small partition (1MB-2MB) with the BIOS-GRUB flag.  Again, if the kernel is readable on the root, it gets run -- same limitations apply as in UEFI if the root is not readable, a separate readable location is needed,
/boot.  Additionally, on old hardware, there may be a limit on where in the root filesystem the kernel is found -- too far into the root, and the kernel may be beyond the addressing capability of the BIOS bootstrap.  This was the original reason a /boot partition was used at the beginning of the disk, to ensure the start of the kernel was not too many sectors into the disk for the BIOS to find it. Making the /boot a separate partition, instead of a root directory tends to cause problems when it fills up with old kernels.  Each kernel takes less than 100MB (assuming standard compression on your initrd file), so with a backup kernel, and an update, 300MB seems sufficient, provided you ensure the old kernels get deleted.  Autoremove may do the job for you, but you can be running the old kernel when an update occurs, and then you may have excess old kernels left around. Start using a later kernel, and you may start maintaining two kernel series, each with a backup, and when updates occur, six kernels may be present. This is probably where
the 1GB recommendation mentioned seems to address.
A few hundred extra MB given to /boot may avoid many problems.